# iterate variable name in java(Tridium Baja)

Tags: java

In Java, is there a way to iterate through a list of variables

(e.g. Avg1, Avg2, Avg3) replacing the number as a variable?

I canNOT use an array, as they don't come through in the Tridium environment.

I need something like this:

```
for (i=1;i<10;i++) {
    getAvg(i).setValue(5);
}
```

I have to use the following format in order to set the value:

```
getVarName().setValue(value);
```

where VarName = name of variable, beginning with a capital letter
and value = value to set the variable to.

Comment: *"I canNOT use an array, as they don't come through in the Tridium environment."* Say what? I can't imagine any Java environment that doesn't support arrays.

Comment: *VarName* is a variable and you'd like to *getVarName()...*? Can you post a piece of code that shows what you are working with? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I can use arrays in the program, but not to output to what the environment refers to as "slots".  These are some sort of physical/virtual inputs or outputs that link to things in the real world.

Comment: Please stick to code as your question pertains specifically to the Java language. For example, "list of variables" doesn't mean anything without seeing where/how they are defined. Feel free to update your question.

Comment: That's the thing, the slots aren't officially declared in code, they're set up either programatically or in the "slot editor".  E.g.    Property 1 Avg1 Dynamic baja:StatusNumeric

Comment: Here's an example of setting up a slot in Tridium programmatically: `getProgram().add( Avg + 1, new BStatusNumeric(0) );`

Comment: It looks like he wishes to obtain a Method called getxxx where xxx is a soft coded name, call that method and get an object, then call a method setValue on that object. That could all be done via reflection, i

Comment: I am on an iPhone or I would type something up. Is that what you're after OP ?

Comment: Yeah...no, this isn't doable without arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do what I needed.

```
for (int i=1; i <= incount; i++) {   

    String ord = getString("BqlOrd" + i);

    Bnum = (BStatusNumeric)get("Num"+i);
    Bavg = (BStatusNumeric)get("Avg"+i);
    Bmin = (BStatusNumeric)get("Min"+i);           
    Bmax = (BStatusNumeric)get("Max"+i); 
    Bdefault = (BStatusNumeric)get("Default"+i); 
}
```

This effectively iterates through "slots" in Tridium programs, which are of BStatusNumeric class.

Comment: You can get all the slots of a certain type like this: getChildren(BStatusNumeric.class)

Assuming you're working in the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't provide any kind of reflection on local variables at runtime, so if I understand you correctly, you cannot do what you're asking about. If what you wanted to iterate over were data members (instance fields) of the class, you could do that with reflection, but not local variables, which may well be optimized out entirely by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use attributes instead of local variables, you can use reflection. That said, if the environment does not support arrays I doubt it will support reflection.

Comment: I actually think reflection MIGHT work.  I had to leave my office for the day, but I will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the Tridium environment, but I'm assuming the Collections framework is out of the question, too...

Try using an `enum` and implementing `java.util.Enumeration`. If you don't have that, take inspiration from it.

```
public enum Foo implements java.util.Enumeration {
    AVG1, AVG2, AVG3, AVG4, AVG5;

            private Foo currentOption;

    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        if (currentOption!=AVG5) return true;
                    else return false;
    }
    public Object nextElement(){
        switch (currentOption) {
                        case AVG1: currentOption=AVG2; return AVG2;
                        case AVG2: currentOption=AVG3; return AVG3;
                        case AVG3: currentOption=AVG4; return AVG4;
                        case AVG4: currentOption=AVG5; return AVG5;
                        default: return null;
                    }
    }
}
```

The code quality's not great, but you get the idea.

Comment: Something like this (or even simpler methods) would work, except that the number of variables will vary.  There is a user definied variable (inCount) that determines how many slots(variables) to iterate through.  Then, the slots are being programmatically added before any actual calculations are done.  If I knew beforehand how many iterations of Avg1, Avg2 ... there would be, I could just tediously code it by hand.

Comment: To help me understand your problem better, what libraries are you allowed to use?